# AZURE Event Hub in VNET or not for filtering?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, vnet

I am having a hard time understanding the docs about AZURE.

I have an Event Hub and would like to filter for inbound traffic (obviously) from over the Web.

But I cannot work out the following from the stuff I am reading thru:

- Can I filter the traffic in Event Hub?
- Or do I need to if wanting to filter associate the Event Hub in a VNET via network endpoint to be able to filter?
- I am getting the impression that any filtering means we need VNET.

That does not sort of make sense to me as it is public facing.

Please advise. I am trying to glean this from the AZURE docs but find it quite arduous and having done a lot of this with AWS recently on the Portal I am trying to save time.

Comment: maybe edit your question with what you are actually trying to achieve (and what you have tried so far)

Comment: I am from an AWS background where all is VPC or default VPC based. I will re-edit.

Comment: ok. what does "filtering" for you mean? Only allow certain producer IP addresses?

Comment: It is related to a degree to the other question. Restricting those who can send messages or rather restricting as in the other question we are now both communicating on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can apply IP-based filtering on the Event Hub. Note: This applies both to the producers as well as the consumer. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-ip-filtering) for instructions how to configure it.

So: No, you do not need VNet integration to apply IP-based filtering. If your consumer, for example, is on Azure, then you might want to use [Network Service endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-service-endpoints) to allow them access to the Event Hub (or Private Endpoints). But this can be done in addition to IP-based filters.

Comment: No, you do not need VNet integration to apply IP-based filtering.   This was what I was looking for.